# How can I display a hidden div on hover and add additional divs dynamically

Tags: javascript, html

I have an `<article>` and a `<section>` which when you hover on the `article`, it shows the hidden `<section>`. It's working fine. However, we need to add this `article` and `section` dynamically therefore changing the css class where it needs to be triggered.

I have a JS fiddle which shows divs which has the same classes and triggers the both of the hidden section.

edit: Here is the [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vanduzled/nD7dW/2/)

What I want to do is to have multiple `div`s and it will update the classes in the javascript and in the css so that I can trigger the right hidden section when hovered on a specific article.

This will be used as a news list which on hover, shows a snippet. backend is ASPX.

Comment: So where is your mentioned jsfiddle?

Comment: Hi Chamika, edited the question to include the fiddle.